# PHP Switch-Case not working with certain string?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm trying to get switch/case to work with some variables and they aren't working and I am wondering why:

```
function convert_time($time_code) {
    switch ($time_code) {
        case "8:00a-10:00p":
            return 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Then the code that calls this function is:

```
$testvariable = "8:00a-10:00p";
$testtimecode = covert_time($testvariable);
echo "TTC: $testtimecode";
```

It always outputs "TTC:"

I went to PhpFiddle and tested it and it also doesn't work there, but I couldn't find a way to make a link to it like in jsfiddle.

However, if I do this code:

```
$time_code = "8:00a-10:00a";
if ($time_code == "8:00a-10:00a") {echo "yes";} else {echo "no";}
```

It will echo yes.

So my question is, what about the format of my 8:00a-10:00a is breaking the switch? and is it fixable.

Comment: If that code is verbatim you have a typo on your function call, should be `convert_time($testvariable);` (missing n).

Comment: Works fine here. But note you've got a typo in the above code: `covert` != `convert`.

Comment: That was a typo on this page, not my code but thank you.  I found my problem and it was another typo.  I even triple checked before I posted on here it wasn't that but i guess the eyes want to see what they want to see.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.
I found my problem and it was a typo.

It should have been 8:00a-10:00a, and it was 8:00a-10:00p.

sorry!

Comment: @MarcB `-10:00a` -> `-10:00p`

Answer (score 1):

Got this to work on my local server:

```
function convert_time($time_code) {
    switch ($time_code) {
        case "8:00a-10:00p": return 1;
    }
}

$testvariable = "8:00a-10:00p";
$testtimecode = convert_time($testvariable);
echo "TTC: $testtimecode";
```

not quite sure what could've happened on your end, possibly something wrong with your server itself but give this a shot.